# Apache Beam ReadFromKafka using Python runs in Flink but no published messages are passing through

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam, flink-streaming, apache-beam-io

I have a local cluster running in Minikube. My pipeline job is written in python and is a basic consumer of Kafka. My pipeline looks as follows:

```py
    def run():
    import apache_beam as beam
    options = PipelineOptions([
        "--runner=FlinkRunner",
        "--flink_version=1.10",
        "--flink_master=localhost:8081",
        "--environment_type=EXTERNAL",
        "--environment_config=localhost:50000",
        "--streaming",
        "--flink_submit_uber_jar"
    ])

    options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
    options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True

    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        (p
            | 'Create words' >> ReadFromKafka(
                    topics=['mullerstreamer'],
                    consumer_config={
                            'bootstrap.servers': '192.168.49.1:9092,192.168.49.1:9093',
                            'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest',
                            'enable.auto.commit': 'true',
                            'group.id': 'BEAM-local'
                        }
                   
                )
            | 'print' >> beam.Map(print)
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

The Flink runner shows no records passing through in "Records received"

[image]

Am I missing something basic?

Comment: Do your elements get printed by the 'print' transform at the end? That might help indicate if the metric itself is inaccurate or if there are actually no records passing through.

Comment: That's a good tip thank you. I did however write out to an external source with no luck.

Comment: So Beam runs in a container, are all the appropriate ports open/bond to be able to communicate with your Kafka cluster? It might be that it may not be able to connect.

Comment: @Cubez, thank you but how would I check this? I've tried with an invalid connection string and I then get a timed out error. So I'm fairly positive the connection is established with the broker when I place the valid connection string.

Comment: I think it's related to this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-11998
I also have this issue. I can make it work wit Dataflow runner, but portable runners and direct runner are not working. If you wanna be sure, just cancel the pipeline and you'll see your events in your output. Or set the max_num_records parameter and it should also work but then it's no more streaming :(

Answer (score 1):

`--environment_type=EXTERNAL` means you are starting up the workers manually, and is primarily for internal testing. Does it work if you don't specify an environment_type/config at all?